# Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, counters

I'd like to automatically repeat section headings after a page break. My naive attempt at doing this is to check the page counter and print the extra text whenever the counter increments:

```
\newcounter{pagecnt}                                                                                                                                                      
\setcounter{pagecnt}{\value{page}}

...

\ifnum \value{page} > \value{pagecnt}% are we on a new page?
  \normalfont\Large\bfseries\sectionheadinghere% print heading again                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  \setcounter{pagecnt}{\value{page}}% reset counter                                                                                                                                         
\fi%
```

Except I'm not entirely sure what should 'trigger' this code? Is it possible or desirable to check after every line-break (or every word) if the page has flipped?

Comment: Perhaps the `everyshi` (which stands for 'Every Ship Out') package is appropriate here? It sounds like you want similar features provided by the `fancyhdr` package

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that's the right track. It seems that I will have to learn more raw tex syntax to get it to format properly, though.

Comment: @cmhughes: Can you provide an answer?

Comment: i interpret this question to mean that you want, at the top of a page when a section continues, the text (for example) "2.3 Title of section (cont.)", and not just the section heading in the running heads.  if this is so, then the suggestion that you look at the package `everyshi` is appropriate.  (i'm adding this comment because another comment points to running heads and footers, which is quite different.)

Comment: a couple of answers dealing with similar situations mention the `afterpage` package: [changing-the-table-of-contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/) and [insert-text-before-end-of-page-and-at-the-begining-of-the-next-page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31710/)

Answer (score 10):

The following patch (via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) saves the sectional content (number, title and font) in a macro that is re-evaluated at page shipout (as supplied by [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi)) if there is text overflow. Overflow is established using the condition

```
\ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal
  % <do something>
\fi
```

that checks whether the gathered page content (of height `\pagetotal`) extends beyond the allowed total (of height `\pagegoal`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\let\@section@title@\relax% Sectional heading storage
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\@xsect}% <search>
  {\gdef\@section@title@{% Store sectional heading
    {\noindent#6\@svsec#8\normalfont\ \smash{(continued)}}\par\bigskip}\@xsect}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \aftergroup\@section@title@% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-14]
\end{document}
```

The sectional content is captured in `\@section@title@` and includes the latest sectional title used (anything from level 1 = `\section` to level 5 = `\paragraph`).

Customizations include using only a *specific* sectional unit (like `\section`, say). Also, to duplicate the spacing after the sectional header when traditionally used, rather than issuing `\bigskip`.

The above works in the context of the standard LaTeX document classes (like `book`, `article` and `report`) and may require additional modifications if used in other document classes, or in conjunction with other sectional heading packages.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to work when `titlesec` is loaded?

Comment: @lyxicon: A completely different solution approach would be required, since [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) changes the entire sectioning structure. I would suggest asking a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a definition of headers and footers. This can be done by packages like [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`scrpage2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)<sup>1</sup>. However most document classes defining some predefined style which can be used by the command `\pagestyle`. Allowed arguments are:

- `empty` -- no header or footer is printed
- `plain` -- only the page number is printed
- `headings` -- depends on the class. e.g. `scrartcl` will print the section.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The documentation of `scrpage2` is located in the manual of KOMA</sub>

Here a small example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case another user stumbles across this answer: `scrpage2` is not the up-to-date KOMA-script package for headers and footers, but `scrlayer-scrpage`.