# Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks (with titlesec)

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec

This is a follow up question to [Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks).
The top answer by Werner works, but not when the package `titlesec` is loaded. Is another solution possible which does not conflict with `titlesec`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost the same, but without the need of `\patchcmd`; just use `titlesec`'s facilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{\thesection\quad#1 (continued)}#1}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{#1 (continued)}#1}

\titlespacing{\section}
  {0pt}
  {3ex plus 2ex minus 1ex}
  {1ex plus .5ex minus .5ex}

\let\@section@title@\relax% Sectional heading storage
\def\print@section@title@{%
  {\noindent\normalfont\bfseries\Large\@section@title@}\par\vspace{1ex plus .5ex minus .5ex}%
}
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \aftergroup\print@section@title@% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-14]
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\print@section@title@` should reproduce the section title's format.

[image]

Comment: I think there's a '}' missing in `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{#1 (continued)#1}`after '(continued)'.