# Re-displaying the _short_ (sub)section headings after page-breaks with titlesec?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec

This is a follow-up to [Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks (with titlesec)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131299/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks-with-titlesec): Instead of repeating the long section heading on any overflowing page, I would like to use the short name (given in `[]` with the section command).

And while we are at it, I also need to do this on the `\subsection` level, so I hacked [egreg]'s answer without really knowing what I was doing.  See my MWE with these changes to accommodate the subsection level (and happy if improvements are suggested wrt applying this to the subsection level):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter

\titleformat{name=\subsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\large}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{\thesubsection\quad#1 (cont'd)}#1}

\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{#1 (cont'd)}#1}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {0pt}
  {2ex plus 1ex minus .5ex}
  {1ex plus .5ex minus .5ex}

\let\@section@title@\relax% Sectional heading storage
\def\print@section@title@{%
  {\noindent\normalfont\bfseries\large\@section@title@}\par\vspace{1ex plus .5ex minus .5ex}%
}
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \aftergroup\print@section@title@% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection[A shorter one]{A very long, long subsection heading}\lipsum[4-9]
\end{document}
```

All that is missing is to display "1.1 A shorter one (cont'd)" on top of page 3:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. Use `\@currentlabelname{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter

\titleformat{name=\subsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\large}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{\thesubsection\quad\@currentlabelname{} (cont'd)}#1}

\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\gdef\@section@title@{\@currentlabelname{} (cont'd)}#1}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {0pt}
  {2ex plus 1ex minus .5ex}
  {1ex plus .5ex minus .5ex}

\let\@section@title@\relax% Sectional heading storage
\def\print@section@title@{%
  {\noindent\normalfont\bfseries\large\@section@title@}\par\vspace{1ex plus .5ex minus .5ex}%
}
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \aftergroup\print@section@title@% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection[A shorter one]{A very long, long subsection heading}\lipsum[4-9]
\end{document}
```