# Memoir: put heading in margin using Expl3 or xcoffins

Tags: sectioning, memoir, expl3, xcoffins

In the `memoir` class manual,
there is the following code
for putting section headings in the margin:

> A less traditional style is to put the whole heading into the margin.
>   I have done this here for a `\paragraph` heading
>   (which is not otherwise used in this manual).
>   The code is:
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
>   \parbox[t][0pt]{6em}{\itshape\raggedleft\leavevmode #1}}
> \newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{%
>   {\llap{\marginbox{#1}\kern0.5em}}}
> \setparaindent{0em}
> \setafterparaskip{0em}
> \setparaheadstyle{\marginhead}
> \setparahook{\setsecnumformat{\csname the##1\endcsname\ }}
> \paragraph{Hang the whole heading in the margin}%
> ```
>
> The macro `\marginbox` puts its argument, raggedleft,
>   into a zero height `\parbox` of width 6em, aligned at the top.
>   The `\marginhead` macro puts its argument into a `\marginbox`
>   and puts the `\marginbox` 0.5em to the left.
>   The `\paragraph` head style is then set
>   to use `\marginhead` to typeset the heading.
>   The format for the number is reset via `\setparahook` and `\setsecnumformat`.

I’ve adapted this to quasi-Expl3,
and referencing the `dim` variables I used in the page layout,
thus:

```
\cs_new:Npn \jcsres_marginbox:n #1
  {
    \parbox[t][0pt]
      { \c_jcsres_marginwidth_dim }
      { \raggedleft \leavevmode \jcsres_section_style:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \jcsres_marginhead:n #1
  {
    { \llap { \jcsres_marginbox:n{#1} \kern \c_jcsres_marginspace_dim } }
  }
\setsecheadstyle{ \jcsres_marginhead:n }
```

<sub>(Irrelevant details elided.
Yes, I could have copied the definition of `\mode_leave_vertical:`
from l3trial/xfont/xfss.dtx,
and used `\tex_kern:D` instead of `\kern`,
but that would not have aided clarity.)</sub>

I’m trying to customize this a bit more,
and I’m trying to use the LaTeX3 tools to that end.
So…

What are the Expl3 equivalents of `\parbox` and `\llap`?
I’ve found a few functions in `l3box`
that almost-but-not-quite fit:

- Corresponding to this use of `\parbox`
  I see `\hbox_to_wd:nn` and `\vbox_to_zero:n`,
  but can I combine them
  to achieve the `\parbox` effect of
  0-height box of given width? and
- I’ve found `\hbox_overlap_left:n`
  which seems to correspond to `\llap`,
  but can I combine the Expl3 functions
  the same way as
  the Memoir example code does the LaTeX2e functions?

Also, this application feels like a job for coffins,
either at the `l3coffins` or `xcoffins` layer,
rather than explicitly playing with boxes;
but I don’t see a way to say,
“Put this box top-aligned with, and 0.8 em to the left of,
the next paragraph.”
Is my intuition leading me astray,
or can I actually make the code cleaner using coffins?

<sub>Later steps (and reasons why I *really* want this):

• As in my post to comp.text.tex several years ago,
“[[memoir] `\marginpar` and marginal section headings](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/EeuV0BOnVX8/1elT13CMtBMJ)”:
I’d like to be able to attach other bits of text to heading.

• See also *[Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47646/2966)*;
I’d like to repeat these headings after page breaks,
perhaps with a note saying, “(*Continued*)”,
and the current code is just complicated enough to scare me.</sub>

Comment: A complete example would make it easier for people to help. Right now, before anybody can even try out an idea, they have to reconstruct a suitable document from the fragments you've provided. Because that is time-consuming and boring, people are more likely to help you if you don't make them go through it before they get to the interesting puzzle-bit.

Comment: I've completed your example. Honestly, why leave people instructions on which bits of code to move where rather than just providing it in a form people can copy-paste-compile? Just to annoy your readers? Especially since the code to be moved is not even formatted as code in the first place.... Grrrr...

Comment: @cfr, after some thought, I’ve removed the MWE in my rewrite of the question. I’m asking about the concepts, not for someone to write working code for me; if I get an answer that addresses the concepts without code examples I’m fluent enough to make that work.