# Can't set font size in EveryShipout

Tags: fonts, memoir, everyshi

I'm using EveryShipout to redisplay section headings on subsequent pages, using an approach based off the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks). I've modified it slightly to work better with Memoir. It works pretty well:

```
\makepagestyle{headings} {} % Disable default Memoir repeated headings, we'll make our own

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \f@rhdr% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
```

[image: Repeating page headings]

Next what I want to change is to have it so that it's the same size as the main headings. (I plan on making it grey later)

I tried both

```
\makepagestyle{headings} {} % Disable default Memoir repeated headings, we'll make our own

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \chaptitlefont\f@rhdr% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
```

and

```
\makepagestyle{headings} {} % Disable default Memoir repeated headings, we'll make our own

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \Huge\f@rhdr% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
```

and even

```
\makepagestyle{headings} {} % Disable default Memoir repeated headings, we'll make our own

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \printchaptertitle{\f@rhdr}% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}
```

but both of them gave the same result:

[image: Weird number appears]

Why isn't the font bigger, and where did this weird number (20.7425) come from?

EDIT: Complete example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}, vmargin=0.5in, outer=1in, inner=0.5in, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\setmainfont{OpenSans}

\makeatletter

% Repeating headings (based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks)

\makepagestyle{headings} {} % Disable default Memoir repeated headings, we'll make our own

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \printchaptertitle{\f@rhdr}% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\raggedright

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\nonzeroparskip

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter heading}
\section{Section 1}\lipsum[7-14]
\section{Section 2}\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a complete example, this will make it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During an output routine, `\protect` is set to `\noexpand`, so commands such as `\normalfont` and `\fontsize` do nothing, because they expand to

```
\protect\normalfont<space>
\protect\fontsize<space>
```

(the space is part of the macro name), and `\noexpand` makes them behave as `\relax`.

Temporarily switch `\protect` to the meaning it has during normal typesetting:

```
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal% There is content overflow on this page
    \begingroup\let\protect\@typeset@protect
      \printchaptertitle{\f@rhdr}% Reprint/-insert sectional heading
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
```

[image]

Where does 20.7425 come from? Let's see: `\printchaptertitle{foo}` does `\chaptertitlefont foo`; `\chaptertitlefont` expands to `\normalfont\Huge\bfseries`; `\normalfont` does nothing as explained before. Now `\Huge` becomes `\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxpt{25}` and, to keep it short, `\@setfontsize` calls `\fontsize{\@xxpt}{25}`. Since `\fontsize` eventually becomes `\relax`, the two values are printed and no font change happens (for `\bfseries` the discussion is similar).

Comment: There's so much to learn about LaTeX. Thanks for your explanation, I understood most of it and it's given me some things to research so that I will be able to understand all of it.