# ConTeXt: Re-display headings after page breaks

Tags: context

How can I re-display the title or subject heading in conTeXt with a suffix 'cont.' after a page break?

Like discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks) for LaTeX...

Comment: Why not use headers to indicate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a one-off situation you could use the `postponing` mechanism like this:

```
\starttext

\startsection[title={Hello World!}]

  \startpostponing[+1]
    \csname strc_rendering_place_head_number_and_text\endcsname
  \stoppostponing

  \dorecurse{5}{\input knuth\par}

\stopsection
```

[image]