# Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks (memoir documentclass)

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, memoir

This is a follow up to Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks.
[Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks)

I am using an the memoir document class and the solution posted no longer works when I change the document class from article to memoir.

Is there a solution for Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks that would work for the memoir document class?

Thank you!

Comment: can you not add a link to whatever you are following up on?

Comment: the normal approach to this is to put the current section title in the page header on each page, which is a built in latex feature, do you really need the heading repeated in the page body?

Comment: In my case, this a reference document and I'd like the name of the document in the page header, and have the section heading repeated in the beginning of the page body.   I have considered having the title of the document on the left and the section title on the right, but these are pretty long headings, and some of the sections contents are really short, so there might be more than one section in the same page body.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to create a multiline header using a \parbox, possible with a blank line in between.  Be sure to increase \headheight accordingly.