# Repeating paragraphs title after page break

Tags: titles, paracol

Usually I have various parts in a document that have titles, they could be paragraphs or lists. As they might undergo a page break I'd like the title to be repeated on the following page with a '(continued)' mention following the title. In my current need it's for two lists side by side for which I used paracol. Here I'm providing an example done with a wysiwyg software.

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/re-displaying-section-headings-after-page-breaks